# Delete directory from SFTP C# using SSH client

Tags: sftp

I am not able to delete  a directory from SFTP server.
I am using sftpclient.DeleteDirectory("TestFolder");
But I am getting exception saying : Failure

Comment: What is `sftpclient`? What SFTP library are you using? What is `TestFolder`? Is that a real value or just a placeholder? Can you delete the folder using a standalone SFTP client software?

Comment: I have a Azure VM configured with SFTP (Secure File Transfer Protocol) or SSH File Transfer Protocol or Secure FTP is a computing network protocol for accessing and managing files on remote computer/server/file systems).

Comment: I use Renci.SshNet library for accessing SFTP server and performing other operations , however I want to delete a folder (in this case "TestFolder") which is on SFTP server. But I am not able to do so. Hope this makes sense

Comment: Do not post information in comments, edit your question.

Comment: You didn't answer my questions about `TestFolder` and about deleting the folder with a standalone SFTP client software.